# Xcode Error w/ C++

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ not even a week ago and i'm using Xcode to write a Rock, Paper, Scissors game for my class. Now I absolutely do not understand why I all of a sudden got these three errors:

```
 locale:
     1. No member named 'length' in 'std::__1::char_traits<char>' 
   ostream:
     2. No member named 'length' in 'std::__1::char_traits<char>'
     3. No member named 'length' in 'std::__1::char_traits<char>'
```

I guess its essentially the same error, but my code was working fine and then all of a sudden every time I tried to run it, it would produce these three errors. I even deleted everything except the main and it still produces the error but this time its only two errors which is the same as above.

If anyone could help me understand why my code isn't working, I would appreciate it.

I was initially going to post my code, but then I realized that the same three errors are occurring with the other program I had completed so I don't believe its within my code that I'm producing.

I can't find a similar error anywhere.

Edit: Here's my code (not complete) -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    // declaring the variables
    string player1, player2;
    string rock, paper, scissors;

    string r = rock;
    string p = paper;
    string s = scissors;

    string play_again;
    string play_game;


    cout << "Would you like to play Rock, Paper or Scissors? ";
    cin >> play_game;

    while (play_game == "yes") {

        // Getting the input for player1
        cout << "Player 1, please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissors: " << player1;
        cin >> player1;

        // Getting player2's input
        cout << "Player 2, please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissors: " << player2;
        cin >> player2;

        // Making sure the players inputted the correct values
        if ((player1 != "r" && player1 != "p" && player1 != "s") || (player2 != "r" && player2 != "p" && player2 != "s")) {
            cout << "Thats an incorrect input. Please enter the designated values of R, P, or S.";
        }


        // Determining whether player two beats player one
        if (player1 == "r" && player2 == "p"){
            cout << "Player 2 wins this round.";
        }

        if (player1 == "p" && player2 == "s") {
            cout << "Player 2 wins this round.";
        }

        if (player1 == "s" && player2 == "r") {
            cout << "Player 2 wins this round.";
        }

        // Now determining whether player one beats player two
        if (player1 == "p" && player2 == "r"){
            cout << "Player 1 wins this round.";
        }

        if (player1 == "s" && player2 == "p") {
            cout << "Player 1 wins this round.";
        }

        if (player1 == "r" && player2 == "s") {
            cout << "Player 1 wins this round.";
        }


        if (player1 == player2) {
            cout << "Tie game";
        }


        cout << "Would you like to play again ";
        cin >> play_again;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You most certainly need to show the code. People around here are decent mind readers, but they're not that good.

Comment: BTW: It's worth the effort to learn about source (or version) control as early as possible, as that makes it easy to see what you have really changed, as opposed to what you think you have changed (there's surprisingly little overlap between the two).

Comment: When using `string` you ought to have an `#include <string>` at the top of the file. That header is guaranteed to include `char_traits` as well.

Comment: I just added the #include <string> but it unfortunately didn't get rid of the errors.

Comment: *Where* do you get the errors? Please add a comment or something in the code you show, so we can see where you get the errors.

Comment: This should compile with no errors if you add `#include <string>`, I've tried it with gcc, this may be a configuration issue with Xcode. In the future you may want to try irc (like [##C++ on Freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=%23%23C++&uio=d4))

Comment: When I click on 'show the issue navigator', and one error falls under the locale while the other two are under ostream. When I click on one it takes me to a very large file that states something with MIT and University of Illinois duel license.

Comment: Well. The code is fine: there is nothing wrong with it. I am assuming it is a compiler problem. It could be that the compiler does not find a specific library or cannot resolve a conflict in libraries. My best suggestion is to reinstall the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your guys attempt to help. Im going to do what Husain suggested and hope it works.